# Laptop screen is black running 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ati

I am running a Dell Studio 1558 laptop - 4Gb ram - 2.4Ghz processor - 500GB disk - AMD graphics
- Been using 14.04 for a week and loving it,
- Have had other issues which have been resolved by checking out ASK-Thanks all

- Was browsing on workspace 2, running an ebook through Calibre and a terminal window and Nano on workspace 1, vlc running on workspace 3, screen then blacked out while browsing with firefox and stayed black, rebooting did not help I have attached a separate monitor which works, my screen blacking out happened once before at the time my machine was running hot and crashing a lot, I reinstalled and have not had an issue with it until now.
- have run apt-get clean and run apt-get update, have tried clearing the list and updating, propriety drivers is not selected in software updates as I found that there was a clash in apt-get update with regards to AMD when it was active.

-After clearing the list and running apt-get updates with the firewall down, which resolved a language-en issue, I get the following error:

-Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

-What can I do to get this sorted?

Comment: Howzit, what I did was completely remove my ATI drivers from my system using:

sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"        Then ran sudo apt-get update               then          sudo reboot           after reboot ran recovery with normal boot, screen is now working again, sweeet

Answer (score 0):

Howzit, what I did was completely remove my ATI drivers from my system using:

sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"        Then ran sudo apt-get update               then          sudo reboot           after reboot ran recovery with normal boot, screen is now working again, sweeet